# Compare UIImage in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, ios7

trying to update my app to iOS 7 i have a problem :

on the iOS 6 version i compare my UIImageView.image to an image into my bundle so i can do stuff depending on if the image is the same or not, i used :

```
  UIImage *imageComparative = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageCompare"];

    UIImage *imageComparative2 = myView.myImgView.image;
    NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageComparative);
    NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageComparative2);

     if ([data1 isEqualToData:data2])
     {
           // The image is the same !
     }
```

Now on iOS 7 this code does not work anymore !

I've been searching for hours for a solution, but nothing.

Can someone help me ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: does it crash or it's just giving un expected results.

Comment: it always return no, when i build using iOS7 the code works

Comment: You don't need to do this usually. It's very expensive, try to figure out some identificator for each image. Like unique file name or url.

Comment: Well it was the only solution i found on this case . . . and i like to understand too

Comment: You should have some kind of source that gives you these images: server(website) or filesystem. In former case you could use url as unique id, in the latter -- file name.

Comment: This code work for me on iOS7 (but I change imageCompare by imageCompare.png)

Comment: Working, thank you very much Jordan !